# Get focus on a JTextField from another panel when a CardLayout changes

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, cardlayout

hi need help on a Swing application that I am doing. I have a dialog with two panels, the first panel has a CardLayout and the second has a FlowLayout. The first layout has buttons that change the card layout and the buttonclick is entered to a specific textfield on the second panel. Every time the card layout changes,  the textfield on the second panel loses its focus. How to get the focus of a specific textfield of the second panel?

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

when you are clicking on a button to go anohter panel

write the code inside the "actionPerformed" of that button

```
actionPerformed(ActionListenet al)
{

//code..

textField.requestFocus();//what the textfield u wnat

}
```

refer this link [Setting the focus to a text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640138/setting-the-focus-to-a-text-field)