# set text cursor in text field, Java

Tags: java, swing, cursor, jframe, textfield

I have two text fields, and text_field2 text_fiel1. when the program is run directly to the text cursor automatically text_field1. I want to ask how can I make the text cursor when the program is run automatically in text_field2 not in text_cursor1???

Comment: May be this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4640138/setting-the-focus-to-a-text-field

Answer (score 8):

requestFocus() method of JTextfield will do. 
look at this http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JTextFieldrequestFocus.htm

Comment: From the JavaDocs *"this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent"*, it's recommended that you use [JComponent#requestFocusInWinow](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#requestFocusInWindow())

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see that a few times in your comments, please have you any rellevant reason(s), because on my `(-: channels side :-)` never ever, I haven't any issue with both (wrapped into `invokeLater()`)

Comment: @mKorbel I think basically what it's saying is the behaviour of requestFocus is undefined because it's function is platform dependent and the recommend method for a component to request focus is to use the requestFocusInWindow method instead